# Test that rails app is inaccessible without a login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, testing, rspec

I have a private rails application that uses Rspec as the test suite and I want to ensure that none of the routes are accessible without logging in.

Is there a way to loop through all the routes and try to access them using the requests part of Rspec and make sure they return a 401 status?

Comment: Err, why? Presumably every route in your site uses the same `before_filter` defined in `ApplicationController` to require authorization, so pick any route and test it. You don't need to test that same bit of code for every single route, that's extremely counter-productive.

Comment: Yea there is multiple devise models, and at the moment they are being used for semi authorization instead of just authentication so the before filters are different for different controllers.  It's not really best practice, but I'm waiting for a chance to implement pundit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all routes and loop through them to test

```
 all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a
```